# Registering or claiming app name in Android app store

Tags: android, ios, app-store, google-play

When developing an iOS app one can register or claim an app name by creating an entry in iTunesConnect and supplying placeholder descriptions and screenshots. **Is there a similar process in the Android app store?**

I'm not interested in squatting on app names. I'm just porting an iOS app to Android and I'd like to have an identical app name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think there is an equivalent in the android ecosystem. Here are a couple of suggestions which may not guarantee the name, but may help in some ways.

1) You can publish a bare minimum app with the correct package name (like com.company.appname). But I think the actual app name part will still be pretty open.

2) Another way may be to buy a .com domain for your app (if it is still available). It may sound far fetched but I believe (I may be wrong) people take that into account to avoid getting into trademarks & copyrights issues. If you have an app that is good enough for being published in multiple platforms, then buying a domain makes sense.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. At what point does the app name become "closed" or unavailable to other developers?

Comment: In the android market (Google Play..), it is perfectly ok to have apps with same name. Like I mentioned, only the namespace(package) matters. But developers try to avoid that in almost all cases because their app may not feature in the search result when user searches for a particular keyword (the other older app may show up). A used name could be a TM'd name. Besides, it is plain boring to give a used name for an app.